# jQuery - how to append multiple nodes to container

Tags: jquery, append, nodes, dom-manipulation

I need to append multiple nodes to a container.  Rather than doing a slow DOM append inside each iteration, I want to queue up the nodes in a document fragment (open to other ideas) and append them all at one time.  Here is my code:

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
$.each( poFailureInfoMultiple, function(i,e){
    fragment.appendChild(
         $('<button/>', {
            'class': 'el-contents-center multiple-record'
         })
    );
});

$('#some-container').html( fragment );
```

My problem is I am getting an error message stating:

```
Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMDocumentFragment.appendChild]
```

So how can I append multiple element nodes to my DOM at once?  I don't HAVE to use the fragment method (I just found it and it seemed viable).

Note: 
**I DO NOT WANT TO USE HTML SYNTAX FOR THE APPEND**

```
i.e. $('#some-container').append('<button class="myclass"></button>');
```

Comment: Where does `poFailureInfoMultiple` come from?

Comment: Why are you mixing document fragments with `jQuery`. `appendChild` doesn't take a `jQuery` object and `$.html` does not take a `DocumentFragment` That's what your error is telling you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var elemsToAppend=$()

$.each( poFailureInfoMultiple, function(i,e){
    elemsToAppend = elemsToAppend.add(
        $('<button/>', {
            'class': 'el-contents-center multiple-record'
        })
    )
}); 
$('#some-container').append(elemsToAppend)
```

The add method on a jQuery object doesn't alter the object itself but returns a new object, which is why you need `elemsToAppend = elemsToAppend.add(...)`. I honestly cant say how fast this method is though. I actually think the html way is faster though.

Comment: I like this solution a lot.  You can sub .append for .html( elmsToAppend ) and it works just ask well.  I'm not sure how much faster the fragment option is compared to this, but I do like the use of .add

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing document fragments with jQuery, passing the wrong arguments. `appendChild` doesn't take a `jQuery` object and `$.html` does not take a `DocumentFragment` That's what your error is telling you.

**Example** http://jsfiddle.net/YNLzg/

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
$.each( [1,2,3], function(i,e){
    fragment.appendChild(
         $('<button/>', {
            'class': 'el-contents-center multiple-record'
         })[0] // passing the HTMLElement to appendChild, not a jQuery object
    );
});
// Can't call $.html() and pass it a fragment, call appendChild.
document.getElementById('ct').appendChild(fragment);​
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  My big question is how much faster is utilizing fragment rather than jQuery's .add ?  This seems like more work but is the return worth it?

Comment: @sadmicrowave  Internally, jQuery creates document fragments, so performance it almost the same. See http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2281-jQuery-Appends-Multiple-Elements-Using-Efficient-Document-Fragments.htm Kranklin answer is nice because it doesn't mix standard DOM manipulation with jQuery manipulation. I didn't do that because I wanted to show you that you were passing illegal arguments to functions.

Answer (score 0):

`$('#some-container').append(fragment.childNodes);` will do the job. For a fun example, run this in the console:

```
var f = document.createDocumentFragment();
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = "<h1>This heading was not here before :)</h1>";
f.appendChild(div);
$('body').append(f.childNodes);
```

The heading will appear at the bottom of the page. (Tested in Chrome, FF7, and IE8)

UPDATE:
To clarify how this applies to the code in your OP:

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
$.each(poFailureInfoMultiple, function (i, e) {
    var btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.cssClass = 'el-contents-center multiple-record';
    fragment.appendChild(btn);
});
$('#some-container').append(fragment.childNodes);
```

Comment: this suggestion does not work.  I get the same error as my OP

Comment: @sadmicrowave: Upon further review, a `DocumentFragment` does not have an `innerHTML` property to use. Updated answer with tested, functional code.

Comment: My OP stated I did not want to use HTML syntax for the element, I need it in object node notation.

Comment: @sadmicrowave: I'm confused. `$('#some-container').append(fragment.childNodes);` is object node notation and will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you would choose html syntax for append ([demo](http://jsbin.com/bahumixi/1/watch?html,js,output)):

```
$(selector)
  .append(arrayOfContents.map(function(s){return "<span>"+s+"</span>";}).join(''));
```