# How to append in multiple element JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML like this :

```
<span class="section2 section4">hello</span>
<span class="section1">World</span>

<div class="tab" id="tab1"></div>
<div class="tab" id="tab2"></div>
<div class="tab" id="tab3"></div>
<div class="tab" id="tab4"></div>
<div class="tab" id="tab5"></div>
```

I need a jquery function able to give me this result :

```
<div class="tab" id="tab1"><span class="section1">World</span></div>
<div class="tab" id="tab2"><span class="section2">hello</span></div>
<div class="tab" id="tab3"></div>
<div class="tab" id="tab4"><span class="section4">hello</span></div>
<div class="tab" id="tab5"></div>
```

My try so far :

```
$.each($(".tab"), function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').substring(3);

    if ($(".section" + id).length == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    $(".section" + id).removeClass("section" + id).appendTo($(this));
})
```

How can i improve my function for correct work?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s2gk70to/)

Comment: what are you trying to achieve??

Comment: @GauravAggarwal First code HTML to Second code HTML of my post using JQuery

Comment: Did you have a look the following stackoverflow answer? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037403/jquery-how-to-append-multiple-nodes-to-container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037403/jquery-how-to-append-multiple-nodes-to-container)

Comment: @pakOverflow That's not what i need dude....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the divs and based on the number in id append the cloned span element. Use [`append()` method with callback](http://api.jquery.com/append/#append-function) which iterates over the element and appends the callback return value.

```js
// get all span with classname start with `section`
var $sec = $('span[class^=section]');

// iterate over div element and append the returned value
$('div.tab').append(function() {
  // generate the class name from id
  var cls = 'section' + this.id.match(/\d+$/)[0];
  // filter element from $sec
  return $sec.filter('span.' + cls)
    // clone the element
    .clone()
    // updaet the class to remove other class name
    // you can also use `prop('className',cls)`
    .attr('class', cls);
});

// remove the span elements from dom
$sec.remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="section2 section4">hello</span>
<span class="section1">World</span>

<div class="tab" id="tab1"></div>
<div class="tab" id="tab2"></div>
<div class="tab" id="tab3"></div>
<div class="tab" id="tab4"></div>
<div class="tab" id="tab5"></div>
```

**UPDATE :** If you want to maintain the other class or the span, then do something like.

```js
// get all span with classname start with `section`
var $sec = $('span[class^=section]');

var $tab = $('div.tab');

// generate classnames based on tabs for removing later
var remove = $tab.map(function() {
  return 'section' + this.id.match(/\d+$/)[0];
}).get().join(' ');

// iterate over div element and append the returned value
$tab.append(function() {
  // generate the class name from id
  var cls = 'section' + this.id.match(/\d+$/)[0];
  // filter element from $sec
  return $sec.filter('span.' + cls)
    // clone the element
    .clone()
    // remove other class name
    .removeClass(remove).addClass(cls);
});

// remove the span elements from dom
$sec.remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="section2 section4">hello</span>
<span class="section1 section8">World</span>

<div class="tab" id="tab1"></div>
<div class="tab" id="tab2"></div>
<div class="tab" id="tab3"></div>
<div class="tab" id="tab4"></div>
<div class="tab" id="tab5"></div>
```

Comment: It append properly the item in container, but you didn't edit the class in function of the container

Comment: I know i didn't specific that on question, but can you edit in the case where span has other class then "sectionX", in the final result i would like keep this other class. If you can't no problem. And thanks you for help

Comment: @A.Rossi :  for that you can do something like this  : https://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/a4nsdrje/

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is you are just removing the original element and appending to similar id div and for `section2` and `section4` span are same so when script works for 4th div it removes from 2nd element and append to 4th.

You need to use `.clone()` and let the original span be at it place just clone it and append on as much div as you want and hide the initial span with css.

```js
 $.each($(".tab"), function() {
   var id = $(this).attr('id').substring(3);

   if ($(".span_wrap .section" + id).length != 0) {
     $(".span_wrap  .section" + id).removeClass("section" + id).clone().appendTo($(this));
   }

 })
```

```css
.span_wrap span {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="span_wrap">
  <span class="section2 section4">hello</span>
  <span class="section1">World</span>
</div>

<div class="tab" id="tab1"></div>
<div class="tab" id="tab2"></div>
<div class="tab" id="tab3"></div>
<div class="tab" id="tab4"></div>
<div class="tab" id="tab5"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try script Like this

```
$.each($(".tab"), function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').substring(3);    
    $('span').each(function(){
        var str = $(this).attr('class');
        var str1 = str.toString();
       if(str1.indexOf('section'+id) > -1){           
           $("#tab"+id).append("<span class='section"+id+"'>"+$('.section'+id).text()+"</span>");
       } 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**[demo link](https://jsfiddle.net/sed6q6vv/)**

```js
 $.each($(".tab"), function() {
   var id = $(this).attr('id').substring(3);

   if ($(".section" + id).length == 0) {
     return true;
   }
   var _this = $(this);
   var _section = $(".section" + id);
   _section.removeClass("section" + id);
   var _clonedSection = _section.clone();
   _clonedSection.appendTo(_this);
   _this.appendTo('#conteiner');

 })
 $("#tmp").remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="conteiner">
</div>

<div id="tmp">
  <span class="section2 section4">hello</span>
  <span class="section1">World</span>

  <div class="tab" id="tab1"></div>
  <div class="tab" id="tab2"></div>
  <div class="tab" id="tab3"></div>
  <div class="tab" id="tab4"></div>
  <div class="tab" id="tab5"></div>
</div>
```

**result html:**

```
<div id="conteiner">
  <div class="tab" id="tab1"><span class="">World</span></div>
  <div class="tab" id="tab2"><span class="">hello</span></div>
  <div class="tab" id="tab4"><span class="">hello</span><span class="">hello</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using new versions of jQuery which support .prop() try this :

```
var origSections=[];
$.each($(".tab"), function() {
    var id = $(this).prop('id').substring(3);
    var sections=$(".section" + id);
    if (sections.length === 0) {
        return true;
    }

    sections.each(function(){
        origSections.push($(this));
        var section=$(this).clone();
        section.removeClass().addClass("section" + id);
        section.appendTo($('#tab'+id));
       });
});
$.each(origSections,function(){
  $(this).remove();
});
```

Otherwise, try this one :

```
var origSections=[];
$.each($(".tab"), function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').substring(3);
    var sections=$(".section" + id);
    if (sections.length === 0) {
        return true;
    }

    sections.each(function(){
        origSections.push($(this));
        var section=$(this).clone();
        section.removeClass().addClass("section" + id);
        section.appendTo($('#tab'+id));
       });
});
$.each(origSections,function(){
  $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**There may have two Case Described bellow:**

## **Case-1:**

If the `id` of the appending `div` are serially increased i.e. `tab1, tab2, tab3 ...` then you can take the benefit of the `"index"` of each element.

Bellow is the  optimized code to do the task.

```
  $.each($(".tab"), function(index) {
     element_index = ++index;
     if ( $('.section'+ element_index ).length ){
        html_text = $(".section"+element_index).html();
        $(this).html('<span class="section">'+html_text+'</span>');
     }
  });
```

## **Case-2:**

If the `id` of the appending `div` are not serially increased i.e. `tab1, tab5, tab3, tab6 ...` then you need to check existence of both the element.

Bellow is the optimized code to do the task.

```js
$.each($(".tab"), function(index) {
 element_id = $(this).attr('id').slice(-1);
 if ( $('.section'+ element_id ).length ){
  html_text = $(".section"+element_id).html();
  $(this).html('<span class="section">'+html_text+'</span>');
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="section2 section4">hello</span>
<span class="section1 section6">World</span>

<div class="tab" id="tab1"></div>
<div class="tab" id="tab6"></div>
<div class="tab" id="tab3"></div>
<div class="tab" id="tab4"></div>
<div class="tab" id="tab5"></div>
```